# How to perform bulk/matrix assignment to strucutre array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct

I have struct array which has field with a lot of POSIX timestamps inside:

```
>> res.machineData

ans = 

  13×1 struct array with fields:

    ...
    fromDate
    ...
```

Now I want to convert them into `datetime`. Although I know how to create matrix of `datetime`s

```
>> datetime([res.machineData.fromDate]/1000,'ConvertFrom','posixtime')

ans = 

  1×13 datetime array

Columns 1 through ...
```

I can't find a way to assign it back to the structure:

```
>> res.machineData.fromDate = datetime([res.machineData.fromDate]/1000,'ConvertFrom','posixtime');
Scalar structure required for this assignment.
```

Other errors reported on other syntaxes I tried.

How to accomplish?

**UPDATE**

I wrote this way with temp variable:

```
fromDate = num2cell(datetime([res.machineData.fromDate]/1000,'ConvertFrom','posixtime'));
[res.machineData.fromDate] = fromDate{:};
```

Is this normal? Can we write shorter?

Comment: What are the dimensions of res? If it isn't a scalar structure you need to provide an index in your assignment. eg res(i).machineData.fromtime = ...

Comment: You see what is `res.machineData`, so `res` is scalar.

Comment: I think [`deal`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) might do what you need without the temporary variable, but I can't test it as your code is not complete. (See [mcve] for guidance on that)